# Creating a Wiki site in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 site set up and would like to add a Wiki site to it. Normally, to add a subsite to a parent site you would click "Site Actions" -> "New Site" and choose the site type (e.g. Team Site) and it would work fine. In the case of adding a Wiki site, I choose "Enterprise Wiki", and get "Error An Unexpected Error has occured Correlation Id:...". So i took the CorrelationId and checked in the ULS files to see what the error is, and the first bad sign seems to be:

> SharePoint Foundation Feature Infrastructure
>   " The element of type 'ContentTypeBinding' for feature
>   'EnterpriseWiki' (id:
>   76d688ad-c16e-4cec-9b71-7b7f0d79b9cd)
>   threw an exception during activation:
>   Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values.  Parameter
>   name: Content type not found (Id:
>   '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39004C1F8B46085B4D22B1CDC3DE08CFFB9C')."

There are more errors in the log, but this seems to be the first one.
Any ideas on whats going on?

Comment: Have you made sure all of the needed enterprise features are turned on at the site collection level?

Answer (score 2):

You have activate the Wiki Page Home Page Feature.

Site Action-->Site Settings--> Under Site Action-->Choose Manage Site Features.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have activated the required prerequisite features, such as web application features